# How to return invalid password error message via Ajax - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have login page where, user enter their Email and password , but i want display a alert or text like (you entered invalid password), when they enter wrong password. i already check `Checkpass` is not null do something and in else  i dont know what should i do to be honest.Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance:)

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Login(string Mail, string pass)
    {

        var hashedPass = PasswordSecurity.PasswordStorage.CreateHash(pass);
        using (DbNameSpace db = new DbNameSpace())
        {
            var query = from cbr in db.Contact_Business_Relation
                        join c in db.Contact on cbr.Contact_No_ equals c.Company_No_

                        join sa in db.Sales_Header on cbr.No_ equals sa.Sell_to_Customer_No_
                        join px in db.PX2 on c.E_Mail equals px.Email_ID

                        where c.E_Mail == Mail.ToLower()
                        select new
                        {
                            Mail = c.E_Mail,
                            pass = px.PS,

                        };

            var user = query.FirstOrDefault();
            var CheckPass = PasswordSecurity.PasswordStorage.VerifyPassword(pass, user.pass);

            if (user != null && CheckPass) //Checkpassword
            {

                Session["Email"] = user.Mail.ToString();

            }

     else {

                // ??
         }

            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#login").click(function (e) {

            var email = $("input[name=Mail]").val();
            var password = $("input[name=pass]").val();
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                data: { Mail: email, pass: password },
                success: function (status) {


                    if (status) {

                        window.location.href = "/Account/Index";

                    }


                }

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

View:

```
        <form autocomplete="on" class="login100-form validate-form">

            <div>

                <label>E-mail</label>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">

                    <input class="input100" type="email" id="Email" name="Mail" placeholder="E-mail">

                </div>

                <label>Password</label>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="password" id="Password" name="pass" placeholder="Kodeord">

                </div>

                <div id="invalidpassword"></div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">

                    <button id="login" class="login100-form-btn">
                        Log in
                    </button>

                </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: Which form of authentication are you using? I don't see you issuing a token or cookie.

Comment: You can set an error message when returns json. Wanna you sample?

Comment: @Tomato32 it will be great if can give me an example :)

Comment: @Marco its just form until now :)

Comment: Before wasting you guys time to answer the question, check my answer and what the guy replied!

Comment: I don’t want wasting anybody’s time and I appreciate all comments my friend :) it’s just Monday u know lol :D

Comment: So you post your task to let someone finish all of it?

Comment: Hell No , I just ask a question dats all.

Comment: Using ajax, and then redirecting is pointless. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. Just make a normal submit, and if there is an error, return the view to display it, other wise redirect in the POST method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks Stephen it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i end up to archive how to return invalid password error message , maybe it help someone on day :)

I created a `enum` to hold the values for MessageType:

```
  public enum MessageType
    {
        Valid,
        InvalidEmail,
        InvalidUerNameAndPass,
    }
```

and then i change my Controller to get different MessageType:

```
    public JsonResult Login(string Mail, string pass)
    {
        MessageType messageType = MessageType.InvalidEmail;

        using (DbNamesapce db = new DbNamesapce())
        {
            var query = // do Join
                        select new
                        {
                            //Select Something
                        };

            var user = query.FirstOrDefault();

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Json(new { messageType = MessageType.InvalidEmail }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            if (user != null && CheckPass)
            {
                messageType = MessageType.Valid;
            }

            else
            {
                messageType = MessageType.InvalidUerNameAndPass;
            }

            return Json(new { messageType = messageType }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

and i change my script to :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#login").click(function (e) {
            var email = $("input[name=Mail]").val();
            var password = $("input[name=pass]").val();
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                data: { Mail: email, pass: password },
                success: function (response) {

                    switch ($.trim(response.messageType))
                    {
                        case '@Convert.ToInt32(YourNAmeSpace.Models.MessageType.Valid)':
                            alert("Valid");
                            break;
                        case '@Convert.ToInt32(YourNAmeSpace.Models.MessageType.InvalidEmail)':
                             alert("InvalidUerNameAndPass");
                            break;
                       case '@Convert.ToInt32(YourNAmeSpace.Models.MessageType.InvalidUerNameAndPass)':
                            alert("InvalidUerNameAndPass");
                            break;

                    }

                }

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jquery tutorial. I personally would use the Fail and Done callback methods. Modify your c# controller to return different HTTP status codes. Use HTTP 200 when they pass a good username and password. Use HTTP 400 when they pass a bad password this should trigger the Fail() callback and allow you to alert on the failure.

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/

```
// Using the core $.ajax() method
$.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "post.php",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        id: 123
    },

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
})
  // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
  // The response is passed to the function
  .done(function( json ) {
     $( "<h1>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
     $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
  })
  // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
  // status codes are passed to the function
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown )** {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
    console.log( "Status: " + status );
    console.dir( xhr );
  })
  // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
  .always(function( xhr, status ) {
    alert( "The request is complete!" );
  });
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing to do would be to set the response status to 401 and omit the usual data payload that would be sent with a successful response.  Then it's up to the client code to recognize the error status and respond appropriately (e.g. perhaps by showing an alert and remaining on the name/password form); this client-side behavior would be specified in the `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example. Hope to help, my friend.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Login(string Mail, string pass)
    {
        var status = true; 
        var hashedPass = PasswordSecurity.PasswordStorage.CreateHash(pass);
        using (DbNameSpace db = new DbNameSpace())
        {
            var query = from cbr in db.Contact_Business_Relation
                        join c in db.Contact on cbr.Contact_No_ equals c.Company_No_

                        join sa in db.Sales_Header on cbr.No_ equals sa.Sell_to_Customer_No_
                        join px in db.PX2 on c.E_Mail equals px.Email_ID

                        where c.E_Mail == Mail.ToLower()
                        select new
                        {
                            Mail = c.E_Mail,
                            pass = px.PS,

                        };

            var user = query.FirstOrDefault();
            var CheckPass = PasswordSecurity.PasswordStorage.VerifyPassword(pass, user.pass);

            if (user != null && CheckPass) //Checkpassword
            {

                Session["Email"] = user.Mail.ToString();

            }

     else {
                status = false;                
         }

            return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
```

In Javascript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#login").click(function (e) {

            var email = $("input[name=Mail]").val();
            var password = $("input[name=pass]").val();
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                data: { Mail: email, pass: password },
                success: function (status) {
                    if (status) {
                        window.location.href = "/Account/Index";
                    }else{
                         $('#invalidpassword').html('You have entered wrong password!');
                    }


                }

            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for example :) but it was not enough :)

Comment: @7seconds: What do you want more, my friend? :))